# Converting Pandas Dataframe types

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame created through a mysql call which returns the data as object type.

The data is mostly numeric, with some 'na' values.

How can I cast the type of the dataFrame so the numeric values are appropriately typed (floats) and the 'na' values are represented as numpy NaN values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace method on dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
df = DataFrame({
'k1': ['na'] * 3 + ['two'] * 4,
'k2': [1, 'na', 2, 'na', 3, 4, 4]})

print df

df = df.replace('na', np.nan)

print df
```

I think it's helpful to point out that df.replace('na', np.nan) by itself won't work. You must assign it back to the existing dataframe.

Comment: You can use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 1):

`df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` will work in most cases.

I should note that this copies the data.  It would be preferable to get it to a numeric type on the initial read.  If you post your code and a small example, someone might be able to help you with that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work e.g. `s = pd.Series([1, 'na', 3 ,4]); s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: Hmm it works for a DataFrame.  I guess they aren't using the same heuristics to recast? EDIT:  I guess the example you gave didn't work.  I was working with something like ```s = pd.DataFrame(['1', 'na', '3', '4']).```  It works for that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to... e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame(s)` :s created [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4119)

Comment: I think its a bug when there is a non-string element

Comment: Was just posting that at the Github issue, but then Github broke.

Comment: I think andy already posted; its a buglet! (but converting to string first then convert_objects does work)

Answer (score 1):

This is what Tom suggested and is correct

```
In [134]: s = pd.Series(['1','2.','na'])

In [135]: s.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[135]: 
0     1
1     2
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

As Andy points out, this doesn't work directly (I think that's a bug), so convert to all string elements first, then convert

```
In [136]: s2 = pd.Series(['1','2.','na',5])

In [138]: s2.astype(str).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[138]: 
0     1
1     2
2   NaN
3     5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: created [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4119)... I guess the standard claim is that it should already be converted before this point!