# Convert whole Pandas dataframe containing NaN values from string to float

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I would like to convert all the values in a pandas dataframe from strings to floats. My dataframe contains various NaN values (e.g. NaN, NA, None). For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_data = np.array([[0.5, 0.2, 0.1], ["NA", 0.45, 0.2], [0.9, 0.02, "N/A"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, dtype=str)
```

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457418/converting-pandas-dataframe-types) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424647/pandas-dataframe-converting-specific-columns-from-string-to-float) (among other places) that convert_objects might be the way to go. However, I get a message that it is deprecated (I am using Pandas 0.17.1) and should instead use to_numeric.

```
df2 = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Output:

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
```

But to_numeric doesn't seem to actually convert the strings.

```
df3 = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='force')
```

Output:

```
df2:
     0     1    2
0  0.5  0.20  0.1
1  NaN  0.45  0.2
2  0.9  0.02  NaN

df2 dtypes:
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
dtype: object

df3:
     0     1    2
0  0.5   0.2  0.1
1   NA  0.45  0.2
2  0.9  0.02  N/A

df3 dtypes:
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object
```

Should I use convert_objects and deal with the warning message, or is there a proper way to do what I want with to_numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely this works:

```
In [11]:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='force'))

Out[11]:
     0     1    2
0  0.5  0.20  0.1
1  NaN  0.45  0.2
2  0.9  0.02  NaN
```

It seems that it's not able to coerce the entire df for some reason which is a little surprising

If you hate typing (thanks to @Zero) then you can just use:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='force')
```

Comment: Look at the docstring, `to_numeric()` expects 1D input. You wouldn't expect that from the message associated to the `FutureWarning.

Comment: @Goyo yes that's true the `convert_objects` method was a df method the top level `to_numeric` only works on Series, tuples, lists and arrays.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if to_numeric worked on DataFrames in addition to 1D input. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Shorthand as `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='force')`

Comment: @Zero sure I can add this, personally I get into the habit of declaring `lambda x` as it's clearer when reading

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_data = np.array([[0.5, 0.2, 0.1], ["NA", 0.45, 0.2], [0.9, 0.02, "N/A"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, dtype=str)

print df.replace({r'N': np.nan}, regex=True).astype(float)
     0     1    2
0  0.5  0.20  0.1
1  NaN  0.45  0.2
2  0.9  0.02  NaN
```